# ¿Cómo puedo desdoblar registros en un DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Necesito crear dos registros nuevos, con cada registro de un DataFrame dado, que cumplan las condiciones  de que 'Concepto = 'REMESA' e 'Importe = 60. Desdoblados todos los registros del DataFarme se deberán eliminar los registros originales (REMESA, 60). Para ello hacemos.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

diccionario = {'Concepto': {Timestamp('2023-11-15 00:00:00'): 'REMESA',
  Timestamp('2023-10-16 00:00:00'): 'REMESA',
  Timestamp('2023-09-19 00:00:00'): 'REMESA',
  Timestamp('2023-08-17 00:00:00'): 'REMESA',
  Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'): 'REMESA',
  Timestamp('2023-06-19 00:00:00'): 'REMESA',
  Timestamp('2023-05-22 00:00:00'): 'REMESA',
  Timestamp('2023-05-19 00:00:00'): 'REMESA',
  Timestamp('2023-04-25 00:00:00'): 'REMESA',
  Timestamp('2023-03-24 00:00:00'): 'REMESA'},
 'F. Valor': {Timestamp('2023-11-15 00:00:00'): '15/11/2023',
  Timestamp('2023-10-16 00:00:00'): '16/10/2023',
  Timestamp('2023-09-19 00:00:00'): '19/09/2023',
  Timestamp('2023-08-17 00:00:00'): '17/08/2023',
  Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'): '11/07/2023',
  Timestamp('2023-06-19 00:00:00'): '19/06/2023',
  Timestamp('2023-05-22 00:00:00'): '22/05/2023',
  Timestamp('2023-05-19 00:00:00'): '19/05/2023',
  Timestamp('2023-04-25 00:00:00'): '25/04/2023',
  Timestamp('2023-03-24 00:00:00'): '24/03/2023'},
 'Importe': {Timestamp('2023-11-15 00:00:00'): 90.0,
  Timestamp('2023-10-16 00:00:00'): 90.0,
  Timestamp('2023-09-19 00:00:00'): 120.0,
  Timestamp('2023-08-17 00:00:00'): 120.0,
  Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'): 120.0,
  Timestamp('2023-06-19 00:00:00'): 120.0,
  Timestamp('2023-05-22 00:00:00'): 60.0,
  Timestamp('2023-05-19 00:00:00'): 90.0,
  Timestamp('2023-04-25 00:00:00'): 90.0,
  Timestamp('2023-03-24 00:00:00'): 90.0},
 'Saldo': {Timestamp('2023-11-15 00:00:00'): -58.8,
  Timestamp('2023-10-16 00:00:00'): 18.03,
  Timestamp('2023-09-19 00:00:00'): 109.26,
  Timestamp('2023-08-17 00:00:00'): 235.83,
  Timestamp('2023-07-11 00:00:00'): 290.63,
  Timestamp('2023-06-19 00:00:00'): 291.08,
  Timestamp('2023-05-22 00:00:00'): 808.18,
  Timestamp('2023-05-19 00:00:00'): 753.44,
  Timestamp('2023-04-25 00:00:00'): 74.7,
  Timestamp('2023-03-24 00:00:00'): 77.57}} 

# Convertir el diccionario a un DataFrame
datos = pd.DataFrame(diccionario)

def desdoblar_y_eliminar_remesa_60(datos, concepto, importe):
    # Filtrar el DataFrame por el concepto y el importe especificados
    filtro = (datos['Concepto'] == concepto) & (datos['Importe'] == importe)
    seleccion = datos[filtro]

    if not seleccion.empty:
        # Crear dos nuevos registros modificando la columna 'Concepto'
        nuevo_registro_1 = seleccion.copy()
        nuevo_registro_1['Concepto'] = 'Trans_1º_izda'

        nuevo_registro_2 = seleccion.copy()
        nuevo_registro_2['Concepto'] = 'Trans_1º_dcha'

        # Agregar los nuevos registros al DataFrame
        df = pd.concat([datos, nuevo_registro_1, nuevo_registro_2], ignore_index=True)

        # Eliminar los registros originales con el concepto e importe especificados
        datos = df[~filtro].copy()  # Aquí es donde asignamos df a datos

        print(f"Se han creado dos nuevos registros con conceptos 'Trans_1º_izda' y 'Trans_1º_dcha'. "
              f"Se han eliminado los registros originales.")
    else:
        print("No se encontraron registros para desdoblar con las condiciones especificadas.")

    return datos

concepto = 'REMESA'
importe = 60
datos = desdoblar_y_eliminar_remesa_60(datos, concepto, importe)
datos
```

Devuelve el error'/tmp/ipykernel_14515/2206961633.py:65: UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.
datos = df[~filtro].copy()  # Aquí es donde asignamos df a datos

---

IndexingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[96], line 76
74 concepto = 'REMESA'
75 importe = 60
---> 76 datos = desdoblar_y_eliminar_remesa_60(datos, concepto, importe)
77 datos

Cell In[96], line 65, in desdoblar_y_eliminar_remesa_60(datos, concepto, importe)
62     df = pd.concat([datos, nuevo_registro_1, nuevo_registro_2], ignore_index=True)
64     # Eliminar los registros originales con el concepto e importe especificados
---> 65     datos = df[~filtro].copy()  # Aquí es donde asignamos df a datos
67     print(f"Se han creado dos nuevos registros con conceptos 'Trans_1º_izda' y 'Trans_1º_dcha'. "
68           f"Se han eliminado los registros originales.")
69 else:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinances/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3752, in DataFrame.**getitem**(self, key)
3750 # Do we have a (boolean) 1d indexer?
3751 if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
-> 3752     return self._getitem_bool_array(key)
3754 # We are left with two options: a single key, and a collection of keys,
3755 # We interpret tuples as collections only for non-MultiIndex
3756 is_single_key = isinstance(key, tuple) or not is_list_like(key)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinances/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3805, in DataFrame._getitem_bool_array(self, key)
3799     raise ValueError(
3800         f"Item wrong length {len(key)} instead of {len(self.index)}."
3801     )
3803 # check_bool_indexer will throw exception if Series key cannot
3804 # be reindexed to match DataFrame rows
-> 3805 key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
3807 if key.all():
3808     return self.copy(deep=None)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinances/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:2506, in check_bool_indexer(index, key)
2504 indexer = result.index.get_indexer_for(index)
2505 if -1 in indexer:
-> 2506     raise IndexingError(
2507         "Unalignable boolean Series provided as "
2508         "indexer (index of the boolean Series and of "
2509         "the indexed object do not match)."
2510     )
2512 result = result.take(indexer)
2514 # fall through for boolean

IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).'

¿Cómo puedo corregir este error?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se debe a que los indices del filtro booleano y del DataFrame al que lo quieres aplicar difieren. `df` es el resultado de concatenar `datos` con los dos nuevos registros, por lo que los indices del filtro booleano generado a partir de `datos` no coinciden con los de `df` (debido a estos dos nuevos registros).

La opción mas simple en este caso es aplicar el filtro antes de concatenar, por ejemplo:

```
if not seleccion.empty:
    # Crear dos nuevos registros modificando la columna 'Concepto'
    nuevo_registro_1 = seleccion.copy()
    nuevo_registro_1['Concepto'] = 'Trans_1º_izda'

    nuevo_registro_2 = seleccion.copy()
    nuevo_registro_2['Concepto'] = 'Trans_1º_dcha'

    # Agregar los nuevos registros al DataFrame y eliminar los originales
    datos = pd.concat(
        [datos[~filtro], nuevo_registro_1, nuevo_registro_2], 
        ignore_index=True)

    print(f"Se han creado dos nuevos registros con conceptos 'Trans_1º_izda' y 'Trans_1º_dcha'. "
          f"Se han eliminado los registros originales.")
```

Comment: GraciasFJSevilla. He implementado tu propuesta y devuelve 'Se han creado dos nuevos registros con conceptos 'Trans_1º_izda' y 'Trans_1º_dcha'. Se han eliminado los registros originales.'. Esto quiere decir que no ha añadido los registros nuevos y sí ha eliminado los registros originales.

Comment: Además, no olvidemos que debería crear 20 registros nuevos.

Comment: La salida es la del print de tu función original, eso no lo he tocado, aunque ciertamente no cuenta los registros agregados, se soluciona con un simple formateo de cadenas. En cuanto a los registros que debe crear, solo hay una fila que cumple la condición en el ejemplo, por lo que solo se crearían dos registros nuevos y se eliminaría esa fila. Para ese mismo ejemplo, si el importe fuera 90 se generarían 10 y se eliminarían 5, a no ser que se me este escapando algo. Una duda que me surge ahora ¿Todos los pares de registros agregados tendrían el mismo concepto  'Trans_1º_izda'/ 'Trans_1º_dcha'?

Comment: Graciass. Efectivamente, me había equivocado al filtrar el DataFrame del que procde el diccionario,. He vuelto a filtralo bien, para obtener un DF con Importes de  60€, he implementado tu sugerencia y, opera correctamente. La duda que planteas, es correcta. Todos los registros agregados tendrán el mismo concepto. Los diferencia la fecha del índice.

Comment: Para eliminar los regsitros originales podemos añadir una de estas dos sentencias "# Eliminar los registros originales que cumplen con la condición

self.movimientos = self.movimientos[~filtro] '"      

       " self.movimientos.drop(seleccion.index, inplace=True)"

Comment: Para eliminar los regsitros originales deberíamos añadir una de estas dos sentencias "# Eliminar los registros originales que cumplen con la condición

self.movimientos = self.movimientos[~filtro] '"  o  " self.movimientos.drop(seleccion.index, inplace=True)". Si no es así, ¿Cómo se eliminan en el código sin ellas?.